# maven-release-plugin and Arquillian

Tags: java, maven, jboss-arquillian, maven-release-plugin

I have such project structure:

```
Parent
  ProjectA
  ProjectB
```

ProjectA produces an ear. The Arquillian based test of ProjectB depends on ear of the ProjectA (create additional deployment with ProjectA ear). Maven install goal works fine but `release:prepare` and `release:perform` are - not. The maven-release-plugin on a one of the first phases increases the version of the project. And when ProjectB constructs a deployment of ProjectA it can't find an artifact with a new version (but it exists in workspace - not in local repo):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke deployment method: public static org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.EnterpriseArchive com.....SchemaCreationTest.createFleetEmulator()
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:434)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.bootstrap.MavenRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(MavenRepositorySystem.java:121)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenWorkingSessionImpl.resolveDependencies(MavenWorkingSessionImpl.java:228)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenStrategyStageBaseImpl.using(MavenStrategyStageBaseImpl.java:71)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenStrategyStageBaseImpl.withoutTransitivity(MavenStrategyStageBaseImpl.java:58)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.MavenStrategyStageBaseImpl.withoutTransitivity(MavenStrategyStageBaseImpl.java:40)
```

I resolve artifacts with such command:

```
Maven.configureResolver().offline().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeAndTestDependencies().resolve().withoutTransitivity().asResolvedArtifact();
```

P.S. `mvn release:prepare` works fine if I set on the dryRun option.

How can I resolve artifacts when maven release:prepare works?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your test cases are structured, having the Arquillian tests as integration tests allow them to be executed separately.
If required, integrate the maven-failsafe-plugin:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Rename your test class so that its detected as an integration test. I.e. rename AcmeTest to AcmeIT, then your arquillian tests will be executed as integration tests, i.e. use `mvn verify` to run the arquillian tests.

This in itself doesn't resolve the problem.  As a simple work around, if this is the only integration tests being executed, you can add `-Darguments="-DskipITs"` to your `mvn release:prepare` and your arquillian tests will be skipped.  You can also add JUnit categories to the arquillian tests and filter at that level.  More info is available on the [maven-failsafe-plugin site](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/junit.html).